# Powershell terminal in VSCode cannot find stagehand

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I've installed `stagehand` and added `%APPDATA%\Pub\Cache\bin` to my `PATH` Environment Variable, but Powershell Terminal in VSCode cannot find it, though in standard Windows Console it works just fine.

What should I do to make `stagehand` work in VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `%APPDATA%\Pub\Cache\bin` to both `PATH` Environment Variables (System and User) and it seems to work just fine.